# Can Office 2010 Standard be installed on Windows 10 S?

Tags: windows, microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2010, windows-10s

Windows 10 S only allows apps from the Windows Store to be installed, but I'd like to know if there's any way that Office 2010 can be installed on Windows 10 S if I download an ISO for it.

Comment: First of all, welcome to Super User! Essentially, you already answered your own question.  Within a Windows 10 S operating system, you can't install software that doesn't originate from the Microsoft Store.  That includes legacy version of Microsoft Office.

Comment: Windows 10, while in [S mode](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2018/02/windows-10-s-becoming-a-mode-not-a-version-as-microsoft-shakes-up-its-pricing/), cannot run any application that isn't a UWP application.  It has other restrictions but that is the primary restriction.  **As of RS4, Windows 10 S, does not exist.**

Comment: So with RS4, if I switch out of S mode, can I install apps that don't come from the store?

Comment: Needless to say, Windows 10 Version 1803 hasn't been released yet.  Currently, if you upgrade Windows 10 S to Windows 10 Pro, it will allow you to install Office 2010 Standard.  Otherwise, you can do as the article states:  wait until Version 1803 has been released and then convert the "mode" at that time. Either way, you will need to initiate the switch.

Comment: You can’t “switch out of S mode” it’s a permanent change.  Just like the upgrade from Windows 10 S to Windows 10 Professional is today